# How to select columns in a table which have values not null in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two SQL tables (I am using SQLite).

```
Table1 (code TEXT)
Table2 (code TEXT, codeTable1 TEXT)
```

How can I fetch all the table1's content which has at least one row in the table 2 with the codeTable1 not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*
from Table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from Table2 t2
              where t2.code = t1.code and t2.codeTable1 is not null
             );
```

This seems like a pretty direct translation of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  a.*
from 
 Table1 a
where
  exists (select * from Table2 b where b.codeTable1 is not null)
```

or

```
select
  a.*
from 
 Table1 a
where
  exists (select * from Table2 b where b.codeTable1 = a.code)
```

Not sure exactly the purpose of your query.

Answer (score 0):

A simple join should do it:

Here's the query:

```
select 
    *
from
    table1
    join table2 on table1.code = table2.table1_code
where
    table1.code is not null
```

Here's the full example:

```
use example;

drop table if exists table1;
drop table if exists table2;

create table table1 (
    code varchar(64)
);

create table table2 (
    code varchar(64),
    table1_code varchar(64) references table1(code)
);

insert into table1 values('CODE1');
insert into table1 values('CODE2');
insert into table1 values('CODE3');
insert into table1 values('CODE4');
insert into table1 values('CODE5');
insert into table1 values(null);


insert into table2 values('VAL1', 'CODE1');
insert into table2 values('VAL3', 'CODE3');
insert into table2 values('VAL5', 'CODE5');
insert into table2 values(null, null);
insert into table2 values(null, null);
insert into table2 values(null, null);

select 
    *
from
    table1
    join table2 on table1.code = table2.table1_code
where
    table1.code is not null

+ --------- + --------- + ---------------- +
| code      | code      | table1_code      |
+ --------- + --------- + ---------------- +
| CODE1     | VAL1      | CODE1            |
| CODE3     | VAL3      | CODE3            |
| CODE5     | VAL5      | CODE5            |
+ --------- + --------- + ---------------- +
3 rows
```